# Java file.createNewFile() returns false though the file is created

Tags: java

So I have this code, where I'm creating a directory, and then inside the directory I create a .txt file. I assign a boolean to whether the file was created, and the boolean is always false(Even when I do a 'fresh run', ie making sure the said directory and thus the said .txt file do not exist, by manually deleting them after they were created in previous runs)

Here's the simplified version of my code

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    File dir = new File("TheDirectory");
    dir.mkdir();
    String path = dir.getAbsolutePath();
    File f = new File(path + "\\TheFile.txt");
    boolean isCreated = f.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(isCreated); //false            
  }
}
```

So, I don't understand why isCreated always returns false.
What am I missing here?

Edit:
Okay, maybe I'm oversimplifying the code? Let me post a more original version.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            File dir = new File("4June");
            dir.mkdir();
            String path = dir.getAbsolutePath();
            File f = new File(path + "\\demo.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            //create file
            try{
                boolean result = f.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(result + "" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                if (result){
                    System.out.println("file created " + f.getCanonicalPath()); //returns the path string  
                    System.out.println("file created " + f2.getAbsolutePath());   
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            //code for writing in the file, reading, other stuff
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns false if the filename already exists.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, I deleted the file before running the program to ensure that's not the case. Anyway, I've edited the question now in case I'm failing to report the situation accurately.

Comment: `new FileWriter(f)` will create file `f`.

Comment: @SimonG. Hm, okay that looks like the case, but I'm not sure which part of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File)) actually mentions that. The constructor only says it creates a new FileWriter object. I'm not an experienced reader of the Java API, sorry.

Comment: @Ayush The documentation does not mention it as far as I can see. It does say that `new FileWriter` will throw an IOException if the file "does not exist but cannot be created", but never states that it will actually create the file. The same goes for `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @SimonG. well in that case, how do we know for sure that FileWriter() was the culprit in our case?

Comment: @Ayush the correct answer was given by SimonG, but if you want to know why read this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/8630510/473259

Comment: Mhm, now if @SimonG. could post his comment as an answer, I'd be able to mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a `FileWriter` or `FileOutputStream` in Java will also create the corresponding file.

I have worked with Java since Java 1.0.1 and `FileOutputStream` and `FileWriter`'s constructors have always created the file.

The JavaDoc does not explicitly state this, only saying that the constructor will fail if the file cannot be created. As no other method is documented as failing if the file cannot be created, it is implied that the constructor must actually create the file as if it did not another method would fail due to the failed creation of the file and no other method is documented in that way.

That said, this is only an implication. A strict interpretation of the JavaDoc allows for the file to never be created nor written to. The constructor will fail if it is impossible to create the file, but need not actually do so. The `write` methods are allowed to write to buffers, not to the disk. The `flush` method is only required to pass the data to the operating system, and the `close` method is only required to release the operating system resources. Nowhere is it promised that the file is actually created and the data is actually on the file.

[The original Java Language Specification](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/javaio.doc14.html) (JLS) did state that the `FileOutputStream` must open a connection to the actual file, and that the write method must write to the file, but this specification was removed from the JLS for the second edition and only the JavaDoc remains.

A reasonable expectation is that `FileOutputStream` and `FileWriter` will continue to behave as they always have. That files will be created by their constructors and bytes will end up in the files after the write method is invoked, and that `flush` is implied by `close`. Any change to these behaviours, whilst within the letter of the JavaDoc, would be considered a major bug by developer.

If you want to have clear documented behaviour, create your Writer with:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("4June");
    try (
        FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, 
                StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        Writer writer = Channels.newWriter(channel, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    ) {
      // write text to the file via the writer
      // ...
      // ...

      // Flush the writer so all the data reaches the channel
      writer.flush();

      // Force the channel to ensure the bytes have reached the disk
      channel.force(true);
    }
```

This promises to create the file and pass all bytes written to the file, but requires more code than simply using a `FileWriter` does.

Answer (score 0):

The method returns false because there was a file with the same name already in existence. See section "Return Value" here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_createnewfile.htm. Somehow, the file is already in existence when you run the `.createNewFile()` method. I ran the code and it returned true. Thus, from this, you haven't given enough information or you haven't deleted the file correctly.

Comment: well I don't follow.
I actually deleted the directory itself, so the file shouldn't be in existence anyway, should it? I'm not sure what additional information I would need to provide, the entire code, maybe?

Comment: @Ayush If `path + "\\TheFile.txt"` is already a file, then this call returns false. It's telling you it can't create a file that already exists. You can either check if the file exists already, and then do something different (delete it, or whatever), or just ignore this return if the file existing isn't a problem for you.

Comment: @SnakeDoc But since I'm deleting the directory 'path' before I execute the program, path\TheFile.txt should clearly not exist, right? I've also edited my question since I fear I provided an oversimplified version of the code.

Comment: @Ayush You're not deleting the directory, you're attempting to create the directory. Calling `mkdir()` doesn't delete and recreate the directory. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()

Comment: @SnakeDoc but I meant that I am manually deleting it, before I run the program. Ie, going to the path, deleting the folder, and then running my program